# how to solve this equation?

Tags: difference-equations

$Q=-{\frac {q \left( {{\rm e}^{{\it nb}\,{\it nv}\,\theta\,{\it Td}}}-1
 \right) }{1-{{\rm e}^{\theta\,{\it Td}}}} \left( 1-{{\rm e}^{{\frac {
Q\theta\,{\it Td}}{p}}}} \right)  \left( 1-{{\rm e}^{{\frac {{\it nv}
\,\theta\,Q{\it Td}}{p}}}} \right) ^{-1}}$

where nb, nv and td are variables.
 nb and nv are integer.
 td is real.
 above equation has not "nice" solution with respect to Q. can I approximate Q? how?

I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: It might be helpful if you know possible range of $nb$, $n\nu$ and other variables, so that you can approximate expotentials.

Answer (score 0):

Write the equation as $$Q = a \dfrac{1-e^{bQ}}{1-e^{cQ}}$$
For example, if $a$ is small we can get a solution as a series in powers of $a$:

$${\frac {b}{c}}a+{\frac {{b}^{2} \left( b-c \right) }{2\,{c}^{2}}}{a}^
{2}+{\frac {{b}^{3} \left( 5\,b-4\,c \right)  \left( b-c \right) }{12
\,{c}^{3}}}{a}^{3}+{\frac {{b}^{4} \left( 5\,b-3\,c \right)  \left( b-
c \right) ^{2}}{12\,{c}^{4}}}{a}^{4}+{\frac {{b}^{5} \left( b-c
 \right)  \left( 331\,{b}^{3}-794\,{b}^{2}c+606\,b{c}^{2}-144\,{c}^{3}
 \right) }{720\,{c}^{5}}}{a}^{5}+O \left( {a}^{6} \right) 
$$
Various other expansions are possible.  We would need to know which parameters to consider as "large" or "small".

Comment: the range of parameters and variables is as follows 0<theta<1, 1<nb<1000,1<nv<1000, 0<P, 0<Td

Comment: And $q$?  That's not the same as $Q$, is it?

Comment: they are different. q is positive variable and q<500. moreover 1000<P<10000.

Comment: It's rather unlikely that you could get a single simple expression to approximate the solution over the whole range of all parameters and variables.  To get a particular value you can use standard numerical methods.